# Getting "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused"

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling, phpmyadmin

I am a student at HF High School, doing a project that involves using the phpMyAdmin MySQL client. I have set up phpMyAdmin on my Mac, except when I try to sign in, I get the error code:

> "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused".

Below, is my configuration file I have copied and pasted on to this document. (I have already tried setting the host to "127.0.0.1", and also to my IP address.).

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 5.0.2 setup script
 * Date: Sun, 04 Oct 2020 03:47:47 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NO';

/* Server: localhost [2] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '8080';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NO';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '4K+W-.d_\\5=P<?@?Py+:0l9p`2$DiiuP';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'index.php';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

Comment: chekc with a mysqlclient if you can connect

Comment: @nbk what does that mean? sorry i am new to mysql

Comment: What nbk means, is the command line mysql client. If installed, you should be able to run the command line: `mysql -u <user> -p` to get into a mysql command shell/terminal. I don't have a Mac, so my help on that system is limited.

Comment: @PaulT. again...I am extremely sorry but I have only started with PHPMyAdmin literally 22 hours ago. I am completely clueless as to what you just said. still have no idea how to get into the terminal (I am guessing you aren't talking about the terminal for my mac, and are talking about some sort of terminal specifically MySQL), and I am also clueless as to what you mean with "mysql -u <user> -p". Do I type the literal command, or is it a template command that I fill out (for instance, if I should put <root> instead of <user> in the command)

Comment: Mac definitely has a terminal, if I recall correctly, there's a command key with a square that looks like that it has loops on the corners of the square. That should give you a terminal on Mac to try that command.

Comment: "phpmyadmin" is not a database. It is a web-based front end for the MySQL database. Is MySQL even running on your computer? Do you know for sure that you have the right password?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I downloaded phpmyadmin. Am I supposed to download mysql as well? I thought that if i downloaded the zip, followed the correct directions to set it up, I would go sstraight to the database once I logged in. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you already have a database, then that's how it will work, yes. We have no way to know whether you have a database. And if you don't know, then that's not a good sign for proceeding, I'm afraid. It's sort of like installing PhotoShop and expecting that it will come with photos for you to work on, or like buying a set of pots without knowing whether you have a stove.

Comment: Hopefully, someone that knows about how MySQL works on a Mac will be able to help you find out whether it's there or not, and if not how to get it.

Comment: How did you install PHP? If you downloaded it as part of a XAMPP or a MAMP installer, you might have it loaded already. If not, then perhaps you need to go to [the MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and install the version for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I didn't even have MySQL installed.