# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused while running multiple instances of MariaDB container in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, wsl-2

I am trying to create two instances of MariaDB database in docker (WSL-2) using two different port mapping. I have created two container by following (in a batch file):

```
 ::create the volume
docker volume create vol1-db-vol 
docker volume create vol2-db-vol 


::create the network
::docker network create Network1

::Run Database script 1:
docker run --network Network1 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 -v vol1-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql --name DB1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbadmin -d mariadb:focal

docker run --network Network1 --name myadmin1 -d --link DB1:db -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin

::Run Database script 2:

docker run --network Network1 --env="MYSQL_UNIX_PORT=3307" --env="MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307" -p 127.0.0.1:3307:3307 -v vol2-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql --name DB2 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbadmin -d mariadb:focal

docker run --network Network1 --name myadmin2 -e PMA_HOST=172.17.0.1 -e PMA_PORT=3307 -d --link DB2:db -p 8081:80 phpmyadmin
```

I can access DB1 (with myadmin1) without any issue. While I am trying to access the database DB2 (with root user and password) from the phpmyadmin (http://localhost:8081/), it shows following error: **mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused**.

I have gone through following post:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919571/mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused-on-live), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444645/phpmyadmin-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462961/docker-mysql-mysqlireal-connecthy000-2002-connection-refused), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201242/getting-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77282354/message-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-connection-refused-in-phpmyadmin). However, those are discussing the same issue in different platform.

The database is running and  this is the output from the DB2 container: `2024-02-23 19:54:15 Version: '10.7.3-MariaDB-1:10.7.3+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3307  mariadb.org binary distribution`

This is the output from myadmin2 container while I am trying to access DB1.

```
2024-02-23 21:05:53 172.18.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:03:05:53 +0000] "GET /index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5875 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-23 21:05:55 172.18.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:03:05:55 +0000] "POST /index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6053 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2024-02-23 21:06:07 172.18.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2024:03:06:07 +0000] "POST /index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6056 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I am using docker desktop version 4.16.0 in windows platform (WSL-2). Please could someone help me to get rid of this issue or at least step to debug the issue. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if this would work better if you let the database server use its standard port: remove the `-e MYSQL_TCP_PORT` option, and change all of the 3307 back to 3306, except for the first `-p` number (so `-p 3307:3306` is the only mention of 3307; change `-e PMA_PORT=3306` or delete it as the default value).  I'd also remove the obsolete `--link` options.

Comment: In that case two database (DB1 and DB2) container will use same port (3306) inside the docker. In case of  editing (insert or delete or modify) database table from another docker container (an example is given bellow), how it will differentiate two databases (DB1 and DB2)? Example: ```connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="p1",pool_size=1,pool_reset_session=True,host=host,user='root',port='*?*',password=pswd)```

Comment: Internally, each container has its own IP address, so there's no conflict.  The actual IP addresses are implementation details, but you can use the container names `DB1` and `DB2` as host names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find it easier to set this up if you use Docker Compose.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  db1:
    image: mariadb:10.6.17-focal
    container_name: db1
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbadmin
    volumes:
      - vol1-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql

  db2:
    image: mariadb:10.5.24-focal
    container_name: db2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dbadmin
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
    volumes:
      - vol2-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql

  myadmin1:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: myadmin1
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db1
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  myadmin2:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: myadmin2
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db2
      PMA_PORT: 3307
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

volumes:
  vol1-db-vol:
  vol2-db-vol:
```

I have used different versions of MariaDB on the two databases just to make things clear. You can revert to `mariadb:focal` when you are happy with the solution.

To launch the stack:

```
docker-compose up
```

In the screenshot below you'll see two instances of phpMyAdmin:

**Instance 1** is server at http://127.0.0.1:8080 and you can see that the database it has connected to is version `10.6.17-MariaDB-1:10.6.17+maria~ubu2004` (consistent with the Docker image, `mariadb:10.6.17-focal`).

**Instance 2** is server at http://127.0.0.1:8081 and you can see that the database it has connected to is version `10.5.24-MariaDB-1:10.5.24+maria~ubu2004` (consistent with the Docker image, `mariadb:10.5.24-focal`).

I believe that this is what you were wanting to achieve.

[image]

If you prefer to run this as separate commands in a batch script then you could do something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

docker volume create vol1-db-vol
docker volume create vol2-db-vol

docker run -d --name db1 \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbadmin \
    -v vol1-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql \
    mariadb:10.6.17-focal

docker run -d --name db2 \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbadmin \
    -e MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307 \
    -v vol2-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql \
    mariadb:10.5.24-focal

docker run -d --name myadmin1 \
    -e PMA_HOST=db1 \
    -p 8080:80 \
    phpmyadmin:latest

docker run -d --name myadmin2 \
    -e PMA_HOST=db2 \
    -e PMA_PORT=3307 \
    -p 8081:80 \
    phpmyadmin:latest
```

But I would strongly advise the Docker Compose approach.

Comment: recommend `command: --port 3307` as opposed to MYSQL_TCP_PORT, the entrypoint understands args but not the env variables (though doesn't need to in this minimal case. Also MYSQL_UNIX_PORT is a path, and also changing it doesn't have an effect. `MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD` can also be used for the clarity that you are using MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @danblack. I've removed `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT`. Other points are helpful too!